# Assign “parcel boundaries” to “census areas” from “MULTIPOLYGON” in GeoPackage file “.gpkg” using Python

Tags: python, polygon, geopackage

In one layer I have “polygons layer” of all “parcel boundaries”, in another layer I have the “polygon” of “census areas”. And I would need to assign every “parcel boundaries” to the “census areas” belongs to. I have a GeoPackage file “.gpkg”. Geometry is in `MULTIPOLYGON` format. E.g. `MULTIPOLYGON (((595568.124 4417209.48, 595563.754 4417209.48, and so on…..)))`

Do you know how can assign parcel boundaries to census areas from `MULTIPOLYGON` format using Python or find more information?
I am reading “.gpkg” file using “geopandas” in Python.

Comment: You want to do a Spatial Join. See [here (geopandas tutorial)](https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins) and [here (geopandas documentation)](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html).

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan. It works using Spatial Join. I just had to do the following before to male it work:
gdf1 = gdf1.to_crs(epsg=3257)
gdf2 = gdf2.to_crs(epsg=3257)

Comment: Please answer your own question as soon as you are allowed to (I think there is a delay between asking a question and being able to answer).

Answer (score 2):

Ids were assigned using a Spatial Join from geopandas:

```
gdf1 = geopandas.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2, how="inner", op='intersects')
```